# How to do a query based on a subtraction result of two datetime objects in a Django query?

Tags: python, django

I have an object `now` that is the `current datetime` object. I would like to do a query that would somehting like this:

Filter all results from `MyModel`, `WHERE the (now - obj_time).days == 0`

Where, obj_time is a `DateTimeField` in `MyModel`. Typically I aim to do something that would fetch me all tuples that have a `obj_time` within the last 24 hours. So what I am trying to do is use the `days` field from the `timedelta` of the `difference of the obj_time and the current time` to see whether its `days field is equal to 0` or `not`. If its not 0 then its more than a day old. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the datetime for 24 hours ago and then do a `gte` query against that.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

target_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)
my_items = MyModel.objects.filter(obj_time__gte=target_time)
```

Comment: Oh yes. This was a simple one. Thanks!

Comment: yep, I just did it based on hours because thats how the question was phrased